# weird sound on windows

Tags: windows-7, audio

About every 3-4 minutes my Windows 7  will make this sound (Windows Exclamation)and coursor is working slow for 1 second but show no message. Is there anyway to fix this or at least find out what program/process is making this sound? I'm managed to stop the sound but this it's not resolving the problem.

Comment: Try to see which program is causing it. What programs do you have on while this is happening? See what programs boot on startup or clean boot your computer and try to determine what program is causing this.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. More details are needed to be able to help you. What have you tried so far? How did you get the sound to stop? Has this always happened or is this a new problem? Is it related to a specific software running or task being performed? Have you run any hardware diagnostics?

Answer (score -1):

Above all: make backups of your important files! Always, but even more so when there's a possible problem.

And yes, there are ways to find out, and probably also to fix (though that obviously depends on what's going on).

Try this:

1. Hit your windows key
2. Type "eventvwr", then press Enter
3. The Event Viewer will pop up. There is an enormous amount of logging in that thing.
4. Browse through the different folders ("application" and "system" are your best bet) and see if you can find an "error"-entry popping up at about the same scheme as the sounds.
5. If necessary, you can "filter the current log" to only show "warning" and "error", which cuts away like 99% of the less important information. Given the scenario it sounds like an error...

This will very probably give you some idea of what's going on. Without knowing more about that it's hard to give further instructions, but since apparently your computer is not crashing or giving nasty error messages or whatever, chances are good that it's not an essential system component but some non-essential process or a third party application. If you find out what may cause it and if you can, try to disable/reset/reinstall the application/component in question and see if it stops.

You can also forgo the whole research step if you don't feel like it and try to "system restore" your system files to an earlier state. (This will not touch your documents, music etc. but may require you to re-install some updates or some applications if you installed any since the date you choose to restore to.) See for instance [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/700-system-restore.html) for more information.

Good luck!